# Javascript class call

Tags: javascript, class

In a few examples of code I have seen the following when calling a class:

```
var foo = new Foo.bar();
```

In which it seems a method is being called upon instantiation. How would a class structure be set up to accommodation this? When I try to directly access a method when calling a new class like this I get an error: call to anonymous function.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not calling a method after instantiation, it's using the provided function as a constructor. It's creating a new `Foo.bar` object, not a new `Foo` object and then calling `bar`.

Comment: `Foo` is just a namespace for the `bar()` constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var Foo = {};
Foo.bar = function () {
   this.variable = "something";
}

var foo = new Foo.bar();
foo.variable === "something"; // true
```

`Foo` is a pseudo-namespace, but really it's just an object. `bar` is an anonymous function that in this case saves a var name `variable` in it's scope.